# Accessing files from inside App_Code folder

Tags: c#, .net

I have a following code in my .aspx file that is accessing a file inside App_Code folder to display image.

```
 <div class="form-item">
 <span class="form-required" title="required.">*</span></label>
            <img id="Image" class="c" src="./sitefolder/api/testing/cImage?xNoCache=<%=DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd.HHmmss")%>" /><br /
        </div>
```

File being accessed in src is api.testing.cImage in App_Code folder.

Something is not right no matter what i try I keep getting error

```
 ERROR "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found"
```

Code is correct as it works fine on the live server. But on my local machine it wont work. I have already given full permissions on the App_Code folder. I have checked already other posts related to App_Code haven't found one like my issue.
Please help!
Thanks

Comment: How are you testing on your local machine? The built-in visual studio webserver, IIS Express or a real IIS?

Comment: Both IIS and built in VS